# Get specific column data in mysql nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a database that stores a username and a pin and I'd like to find the username and verify that it exists to print the pin to the console, but I can't find how to do it.

This is the method I use to check if the user exists.

```
conection.query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = '499642019191324692'", function(err, result, field){
    if(result.length === 0){
        console.log("Does not exist");
    }else{  
        console.log("This user exists"); 
        
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just log the value in `result[0]['pin']`, replacing `pin` with the name of the column that holds the PIN value, if not named as such:

```
conection.query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = '499642019191324692'", function(err, result, field){
    if(result.length === 0){
        console.log("Does not exist");
    } else {  
        console.log("This user exists"); 
        console.log(result[0]['pin']);     
    }
});
```